# MBProgressHUD Hides too quickly

Tags: ios, ios7, grand-central-dispatch, mbprogresshud

I am utilizing MBProgressHUD along with STTwitter...I call MBProgressHUD and then load the twitter feed off the main thread and hide the HUD thereafter. Unfortunately, the HUD hides as soon as it receives a response and not necessarily after the data has completely downloaded. Is there a solution to this? This also occurs with webviews elsewhere in the app. Thanks!

```
[[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    //Sets the auth key (user or app) for the RMACC Twitter Feed
    STTwitterAPI *twitter = [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIOSWithFirstAccount];
    [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {
        [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"RMACCNewsNotes" count: 10 successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            });

            self.twitterFeed =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }


                                    errorBlock:^(NSError *error){

                                    }];

    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        [self twitterselfauthrequest];
    }];

        });

}
```

Comment: have you tried to implement maybe some own stuff as HUD?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD) which is easy to use, implements Singleton, and with much more functionality and control

Comment: same situation using SV HUD as well. At least this helped me determine it wasn't MB

Answer (score 0):

Move your `HUD` hiding code inside `successBlock` as follows

```
successBlock: ^(NSArray *statuses) {

                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                          [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                          });

                  self.twitterFeed =[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

                  [self.tableView reloadData];
              }
```

Comment: This results in it never hiding...I have updated the code to reflect the change and also to show the other error blocks and such

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `dispatch_async` to `dispatch_sync`.
I think this might be happening because of some issues dispatch_async has on main thread.